# Do I need to inject properties in both init(coder) and init(size)?

Tags: ios, constructor, sprite-kit, initialization

I'm trying to set `property` values in my `SpriteKit` project using a `constructor` (`init`). Since `swift` doesn't inherit `init` `methods` it's not always as simple as just adding a clean `init()` method and take it from there. My project require me to include both the `init(size)` and `init(coder)` methods. That's fine.

However, this also seem to mean that I need to inject my `properties` in both `init` methods. To me that seems a bit redundant, but the `compiler` forces me to do so. So, my question is, is this the way to do it, or is there a cleaner way, so I don't need to use two `init` `methods` that set the same `property` values? Here's what the code look like:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let myVariable: SKShapeNode

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        myVariable = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        myVariable = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

...and the class calling `GameScene`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

       let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
       scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
       scene.size = view.frame.size
       scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0 , y: 1)
       view.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Comment: using `let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)` is "inefficient" , and makes `scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill` and
       `scene.size = view.frame.size` useless.  It goes against many of the reasons as to why SpriteKit exists in the first place, one of which is scaling once instead of having to multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the coder init isn't being used (e.g., you're creating the scene only programmatically).  Then you can just stub out the required coder init:

```swift
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Edit: As Ron points out, if you're using the editor to create the scene and are loading if from an SKS file, the coder init is the one that you have to implement.

Comment: Ah, very nice, thanks a lot! Is it the fatalError part that has to be included to not having to use super and set my property? Any good explanation to why?

Comment: The compiler knows that fatalError aborts the program.

Comment: @bg2b you should explain in your answer, the opposite as well. that if the scene is created in the scene editor you MUST have required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) setup and do not need the other init

Comment: I wouldn't say "often", since more often than not you are going to use the decoder with the encoder when you want to save the scene for a later date.  It goes beyond just scene builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by doing by defining it in your let statement providing `self` is not used, or doing via `lazy`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let myVariable: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}




class GameScene: SKScene {
   lazy var myVariable: SKShapeNode = {
       var node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
       //Maybe we want to add it to the scene here
       return node
   }

   override init(size: CGSize) {
   super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}